# Corrupt pointer when using Realm in iOS app after upgrading from Xcode 9.4 to Xcode 11 and Swift 3.0 to Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I have a hybrid app with Swift and Objective-C code. When running the code in Xcode 9.4 there was no issues. After upgrading to Xcode 11 (plus requested upgrade to Swift 4.2) the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while attempting to reference a deallocated instance in the Realm 0.93.2 library.

Here are the sequence of events:

1. Start up:

```
        @UIApplicationMain
    class VGPAppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, BITCrashManagerDelegate, BITHockeyManagerDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?

        internal func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            //trigger the ui appearance
            VGPUIAppearance.triggerAppearance()

            //setup network monitoring
            TSReachabilityManager.default()
            //Update Realm Scheme
            VGPRealmMigrator.updateRealmSchema()

            setUpHockeyApp()
            setupAppearance()

            if didCrashInLastSessionOnStartup() {
                // Delay launch for sending the crash report
            } else {
                setupApplication()
            }

            return true
        }
```

2. Following call to VGPRealmMigrator.updateRealmSchema()

```
    for (Class cls in s_localNameToClass.allValues) {
    RLMObjectSchema *schema = [RLMObjectSchema 
    schemaForObjectClass:cls];
    [schemaArray addObject:schema];

            // override sharedSchema classs methods for performance
            RLMReplaceSharedSchemaMethod(cls, schema);

            // set standalone class on shared shema for standalone object creation
            schema.standaloneClass = RLMStandaloneAccessorClassForObjectClass(schema.objectClass, schema);
        }
        free(classes);
```

Note: schema has a valid pointer here in Realm > RLMSchema.mm > Intitialise

1. Now in Realm > RLMAccessor.mm

```
    static Class RLMCreateAccessorClass(Class objectClass,
                                        RLMObjectSchema *schema,
                                        NSString *accessorClassPrefix,
                                        IMP (*getterGetter)(RLMProperty *, RLMAccessorCode, NSString *),
                                        IMP (*setterGetter)(RLMProperty *, RLMAccessorCode)) {
        // throw if no schema, prefix, or object class
        if (!objectClass || !schema || !accessorClassPrefix) {
            @throw RLMException(@"Missing arguments");
        }
        if (!RLMIsKindOfClass(objectClass, RLMObjectBase.class)) {
            @throw RLMException(@"objectClass must derive from RLMObject or Object");
        }

        // create and register proxy class which derives from object class
        NSString *accessorClassName = [accessorClassPrefix stringByAppendingString:schema.className];
        Class accClass = objc_getClass(accessorClassName.UTF8String);
        if (!accClass) {
            accClass = objc_allocateClassPair(objectClass, accessorClassName.UTF8String, 0);
            objc_registerClassPair(accClass);
        }
```

App crashes in statement containing reference **schema.className**. Here schema has null pointer. Zombie shows 'Message sent to deallocated instance'.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an ancient version (0.93.2) of Realm. Fixed the problem by:

1. pod install --repo-update
2. pod install (that gave me the latest version which is 3.17.3)